# New line in twitter API abraham\TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

After implementing the necessary changes to support emojis into my database I have came across this problem where I can't seem to fit a new line into posting a new `tweet` to `Twitter`.

Lets suppose I have the following code:

```
$parameters = [
    'status'    => "Foo. \n New line",
];
```

`Twitter` will render it correctly since it is in `"`. If I happen to do the following:

```
$parameters = [
    'status'    => 'Foo. \n New line',
];
```

`Twitter` will render `Foo. \n New Line`.

My questions starts when I need to update the status with a new line terminator `\n` in it.

```
$tweet = $dataFromDatabase;
$parameters = [
    'status' => $tweet
]
```

`Twitter` will render the literal string coming from the database (which in this example we can suppost it is `Foo. \n New Line`).

I suppose the problem comes from using `'` instead of `"`.

**Question**

How I can make `Twitter` read the `$tweet` variable correctly displaying the content formated correctly?

I have tried the following solutions without success:

```
$parameters = [
    'status'    => '"'. $tweet .'"',
];
$parameters = [
    'status'    => addslashes($tweet),
];
$parameters = [
    'status'    => "{$tweet}",
];
```

Comment: If string in database __has__ newline - then twitter will use it. So, the problem is in format of strings.

Comment: This started to happen because I changed the collation of the table: `charset = utf8mb4 and collation = utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Before there was literally a new line in the database but now it stores the `\n` instead of a formated text. I did this change to be able to support emojis

Comment: So now you need a script which will replace `\n` to `"\n"` either in your database or before posting to twitter.

Comment: @u_mulder I'm storing into the database as it is coming from the user: `$x = trim($dataPassed);`. Any idea how I would to convert that `\n` to `"\n"`? No need for a script because these are all fresh records

Comment: I don't understand - if user inputs new line, then new line is in text. What's the problem?

Comment: @u_mulder I feel so dumb right now. I was using `<input>` instead of `<textarea>`. I was mannually placing `\n`. Probally need some resting. Thank you and I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to publish a new message with line breaks, in PHP, the code is:

```
$parameters = array("status" => "Content of the first line" . chr(13) . chr(10) . "Content of the second line");
```